# При создании проекта в Unity выдает вот такую ошибку, кто знает как исправить?

Tags: unity3d

[image: Левый нижний угол]

5 раз уже переустанавливал Unity, пытался создать на других версиях - ничего не помогает. В момент создания проекта Unity просто закрывается, но при повторном входе в HUB проект есть в Projects, а если попытаться в него зайти то выдает ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема именно в том, что и пишет Hub. А пишет он, что путь для указанного проекта не существует. Проверьте ваш диск и убедитесь, что директория ровно такая, как указана в проекте.

Если что-то не совпадает, то нажмите кнопку "Add" в Unity Hub (правый верхний угол) и добавьте папку с проектом вручную

Comment: Добрый день! проекта в папках нет, он не создается. Все происходит так: в Hub создаю новый проект, Hub закрывается, я снова его открываю и вижу в Projects, что проект создался, но при поиске в папках его нет.

Comment: УРА, мне удалось пофиксить это. Оказывается, что дело было в microsoft visual c++ 2015 - 2019г, я просто переустановил их.